# Ant-Design Upload how to upload a file to a directory in your project file

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, upload, components, antd

I have been trying to upload a file from my computer into my project directory using the Ant Design Upload component. Once it is uploaded, I can do whatever I want with it but I am repeatedly getting this error:

`POST file:///home/usr/app/uploadedFiles net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I don't know why it says 'file not found' since I just want to specify the file path I provide as the location for what I upload. In the docs, it specifies that 'action' is the url for whatever you want to upload but I do not see why a file path should cause any issues. They are using `XMLHttpRequest();` as their backend for uploading files.

You can find the antd upload docs [here](https://ant.design/components/upload/).

It is important to note, that although the error is there, a new file still appears in the list of files below the upload and is added to fileList in the state. The problem is that I need those files to be saved in a directory within the project itself as well, instead of just temporarily in my component.

My relevant code is below. I am of course using React.

```
  uploadedBundle = (info) => {
    console.log(info)
    if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      console.log(info);
    } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
      console.log(info.fileList);
    }
    this.setState({
      fileList: info.fileList,
      size: +info.file.size
    })
  }
  render() {
    const uploads = {
      action: __dirname + '/uploadedFiles',
      listType: 'picture',
      defaultFileList: this.state.fileList,
      onChange: this.uploadedBundle
      // customRequest: this.uploadedBundle
    };
    return (
      <Upload {...uploads}>
        <Button className='modal-button login-form-button'>
          <Icon type="upload">Upload A Study</Icon>
        </Button>
      </Upload>
    )
  }
```

Comment: did you ever solve the issue? Running into this myself, while it works, i wanna stop the post error i keep getting so the image wont be in a red box

Answer (score 0):

You have to create any NodeJs server on your local PC to do it